# При загрузке cookies через selenium (vk.com) ошибка "too many redirects". Python

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

Есть учебный код для изучения **selenium**

```
import pickle
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class Driver:
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.browser = driver
        print("Инициализован драйвер Firefox")
        

    def open_page(self, page:str):
        self.browser.get(page)
        print(f"Открыта страница {page}")

    def reload_page(self):
        self.browser.refresh()

    def make_screenshot(self, filename:str):
        self.browser.save_screenshot(filename)
        print(f"Sreenshot saved in {filename}")


    def click_element(self, class_name:str):
        self.element = self.browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)
        self.element.click()


    def input_keys(self, text):
        self.element.send_keys(text)
    

    def quit(self):
        print("Goodbye!")
        self.browser.quit()
    

class Cookies():
    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.browser = driver


    def save_cookies(self):
        return self.browser.get_cookies()


    def load_cookies(self, cookie):
        self.browser.add_cookie(cookie)
        

if __name__== "__main__":
    Firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
    Firefox.set_window_size(535, 730)
    Browser = Driver(Firefox)
    Cookies = Cookies(Firefox)

    Browser.open_page("https://vk.com")

    files = os.walk("./")
    coockies_not_exists = True
    for value in list(files)[0][2]:
        if value == 'vk_cookies.pkl':
            print("Файл cookies найден!")
            coockies_not_exists = False
            for cookie in pickle.load(open("vk_cookies.pkl", "rb")):
                Cookies.load_cookies(cookie)
            Browser.reload_page()
            break

    if coockies_not_exists:
        input("Файл coockies не найден...\nАвторизуйтесь и нажмите enter. ")
        pickle.dump(Cookies.save_cookies(), open("vk_cookies.pkl", "wb"))

    Browser.quit()
```

Первая загрузка страницы работает, все загружается и куки сохраняются в папку со скриптом, ошибки нет.
2 же запуск работает до полной загрузки страницы (Куки загрузились, в аккаунт вошел), но после сразу ошибка **"Too many redirects"**.

**Текст ошибки:**

```
Инициализован драйвер Firefox
Открыта страница https://vk.com
Файл cookies найден!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pixart/projects/python/selenium/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    Browser.reload_page()
  File "/home/pixart/projects/python/selenium/main.py", line 18, in reload_page
    self.browser.refresh()
  File "/home/pixart/projects/python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 570, in refresh
    self.execute(Command.REFRESH)
  File "/home/pixart/projects/python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pixart/projects/python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=redirectLoop&u=https%3A//vk.com/&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20has%20detected%20that%20the%20server%20is%20redirecting%20the%20request%20for%20this%20address%20in%20a%20way%20that%20will%20never%20complete.
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:189:5
UnknownError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:768:5
checkReadyState@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.sys.mjs:58:24
onNavigation@chrome://remote/content/marionette/navigate.sys.mjs:324:39
emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.sys.mjs:154:20
receiveMessage@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteEventsParent.sys.mjs:33:25
```

Он же загрузил страницу, все показывается, а потом резко ошибка... Защита от ботов?
Firefox, linux, python 3.10.